# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python, cryptography, sha256, pycrypto, rsa-sha256

I installed Crypto module and SHA256 but showing ModuleNotFoundError
:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Digitalsig.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from Crypto.Hash import SHA256 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Here is the refrence code

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read

#used to generate a keypair which contain a public and private key
keyPair = RSA.generate(1024,random_generator)
pubKey = keyPair.publicKey()

plainText = 'Hello World'
hashA = SHA256.new(plainText).digest()
digitalSignature = keyPair.sign(hashA,'')

print("Hash A: "+repr(hashA) + "\n");
print("Digital Signature: " + repr(digitalSignature) + "\n")

#Bob receives the plainText and digitalSignature from Alice 
#plainTextChanged ='Hello World'
hashB =SHA256.new(plainText).digest()
print("Hash B: " + repr(hashB) + "\n")

if(pubKey.verify(hashB, digitalSignature)):
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No Match")
```

Comment: Did you check that the module is installed? Is it installed in the right environment (Python2/Python3 for instance)?

Comment: yes i have seen that..it is in correct environment

Answer (score 6):

First install a module using pip

1. Open Cmd
2. write command
   `pip install pycrypto` 
   (It require installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0)
3. Then use it in your code as you use in your code above

Comment: use `pycryptodome`, the newer, less vulnerable, official, and supported version. 

`pip install pycryptodome`

https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/faq.html#